# What is the use of Pair Class and why have the implemented here?

Tags: java

What is the difference between a `Pair Class and a HashMap`. I see both of them having `key and value`.

**Code Earlier:**

```
 List<Patient> patientDetails = new ArrayList<Patient>();
 Patient patientInfo = new Patient();
 patientInfo.setReligion(Constants.ReligionArray[custom.getReligion()]);
 patientDetails.add(patientInfo);
```

The code has been changed to this today.

**Changed Code**

```
List<Pair<String, String>> patientInfo = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
patientInfo.add(new Pair<String, String>("Religion", Constants.ReligionArray[custom.getReligion()]));
```

1. Why have they implemented a `Pair Class here?` What could be the reason.
2. What is the difference between a `Pair Class and a HashMap`.

Note: Both the code works perfectly.

Comment: Why? Probably because storing everything about a patient in one object is not a good idea, for security and otherwise. This way you can abstract the access to the patients information.

Comment: I take you don't know about the hash table data structure, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I talk about the difference between a Pair and a HashMap, let me tell you why that's not really the question you want answered.  What you really want to know is why would you take an Object and break it into a list of key/value primitivies.

The code you are referencing is converting from an object oriented approach of using a class `Patient` (which really looks like it should be called `PatientInfo`) into a list of primitives, they are essentialy "deObjectOrienting" the class.

So in their model each class variable becomes a `Pair` where the variable name become the key, and the variable value become the value.

Here is an expanded example class

```
// Old style (Object oriented)
class PatientInfo{
    String religion;
    String address;
}
PatientInfo patientInfo = new PatientInfo();
patientInfo.setReligion("myReligionName"); 
patientInfo.setAddress("address of the patient"); 

// New Style, key/value primitive pairs (very not object oriented)
Pair<String,String> religionInfo = new Pair<String,String>("religion","myReligionName");
Pair<String,String> addressInfo = new Pair<String,String>("address","address of the patient");
```

They then add these either the `Patient` or the `Pair` into a List.

Why would someone do this is a good question. Most people try to become more object oriented as it makes coding easier. Perhaps since it's only a single variable in the Clss they figured why not remove the class entirely?

To your original question between a Pair and a HashMap. A Pair is just a key/value.  A HashMap is the collection usually used to store many key/value pairs. Here they are using a List where they should probably be using the HashMap.

Answer (score 12):

I think that the question you're asking is: what is the difference between
`List<Pair<T,S>>` and `HashMap<T,S>`. There are many.

**In general**, a `Map` object is used to associate a value with a key and provide means to quickly get the values based on the key. There can usually be a single value associated with one key.

A `List` is an ordered container in which objects are stored, provides means to iterate over its contents and get an element based on it's location in list (get Nth element). Usually the same elements may be duplicated within a list.

**In your case**, when you are using a list, your patients can have a several religions. To find what kind of religion your patient has, you have to manually search the list for the pair with the first element set to religion.

Had you used a map, each patient would have a single religion associated with him (or none). You could also find the religion quickly through `Map<String,String>.get(String key)`

Comment: A model which supports several religions per person---what a great idea to teach the meaning of *overengineering*!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's an unfortunate example, sorry:/ But i guess storing phone numbers or other 1-many entities is a possibility in "patientDetails".

Comment: I forgot to put a smiley, sorry :-) I wrote that for laughs.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, your code has been changed away from typical Java approach into what is most often referred to as "object denial". The replacement that happened is from a dedicated domain object `Patient` into a generic `Pair<String, String>`.

So you are asking about the difference between `List<Pair<String,String>>` and a `Map<String,String>`. The former contains more information because it maintains the insertion order of the individual pairs and also allows random access based on position in the list.

A `Map`, on the other hand, allows efficient lookup based on the key, which is what is really needed.

Answer (score 8):

1. The `Pair` class is just a structure with two fields, that doesn't have a special name (unlike `Person`). Pairs (and more generally, tuples) are often used in languages like Python when you don't want to give a name to some intermediate structure. In your case, instead of (possibly) under-defined `Person` object you have a simple fully-defined object. Perhaps, the usage of `Pair` is questionable in Java, beacause of a rather clumsy syntax (compare to Python, where the pair would be just `("Religion", religions)`).
2. You can think of `Map` as a collection of pairs with the unique constraint on the first element.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class can be compared to the [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) of a HashMap. A HashMap may contain multiple key/value pairs stored and looked up efficiently by the key.

A List of Pairs cannot be looked up by the key without iterating inefficiently (depending on the size), but it can be referenced by index. There is also nothing enforcing one and only one key in the list.

Answer (score 1):

A `Pair` object stores exactly one key and one value. A `HashMap` is a structure where you can store several key/value pairs.

Comment: Actually, a `HashMap` is a `Map`, not a `Collection`.

Comment: With generics a Pair<S,T> would make sense.

Comment: A pair does not necessarily consist of a key and a value. it may as well consist of two values. e.g. think of coordinates in 2D

Answer (score 0):

A "pair" is a pair of items that you want to be related in some way or another.  There is no key enforcement, lists of items or anything else.  It is simply a shortcut for when you have a pair of items that are really most useful as a pair of items, but simple enough structure where there is no need to create a separate class to relate them.  Examples: points on a rectangle, ip addresses to domains, etc.

A hashmap can be thought of as a mapping of pairs, with an enforcement of a "key" specification.  In this case the first item of the pair becomes "constant" and is used to refer to the second item.  In my example of pairs I used ip addresses to domains.  In this case we would use the domain as the "key" and use it to refer to the ip address of the machine.  This IP adress could of course change, but the domain would always be the same, and is used to quickly look up the currently associated ip address.  Note, that the restriction of the first item in the pair being the "key" come from the hash map, and not the specification of pair istelf.  The hash part of hashmap then refers to how items are looked up, in this case a hash table, on the 'first' item in the pair...